# How to add a JAR to an Eclipse plugin I am developing?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin. It has other plugin/feature dependencies. However I want to add my own favorite JAR/libriaries to it, like say logback for example. How can I do this so that when I eventually deploy it to an update site, it will have these jars on the classpath?

Also, I am currently using eclipse to run the plugin (it opens another instance of eclipse) to run this. This will also need to have the jar on the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these steps :-

1. Use Import>File System to import the jar files into your plugin project, say in the /lib directory.
2. Use "Add..." to add the jars to the classpath section of the plugin.xml>Runtime tab.
3. Use "New..." to add "." library back (with no quotes, of course).
4. make sure your binary build exports the new jar files on the plugin.xml>Build tab.
5. save.
6. on the project, use context menu>PDE Tools>Update Classpath to correctly add the jars to the eclipse project classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In plugin-manifest editor select `Runtime` tab and add you jar in classpath section.